# How can I scrape this site python and websockets?

Tags: python, web-scraping, websocket, python-requests

Hi I am to use `websockets` to request data from this site https://dexscreener.com/new-pairs. I previously managed to scrape this site through `requests` like so:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://dexscreener.com/new-pairs')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
```

This no longer reaches the `<main>` tag of data which I would like to read. I feel like I am close to getting a `websockets` method to work but not quite there yet

```py
import json, socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

sio.connect("https://io.dexscreener.com/", socketio_path='u/ws3/screener3/')
```

but this is producing an error:

```
socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Unexpected status code 403 in server response
```

This is the full websockets path I can see:

```
"wss://io.dexscreener.com/u/ws3/screener3/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=0hOBuQxbhAw5SHEVAN2F"
```

How can I get this to work and recieve the desired data in the picture below? thanks
[image: chrome websockets inspection]

Comment: I would guess that you need to take the final `/` out of the domain and put it at the beginning of the `socketio_path`.  I think those paths need to be absolute.

Comment: @TimRoberts Didn't work unfortunately

Comment: And did you try the obvious `sio.connect("https://io.dexscreener.com/u/ws3/screener3/')`?  `socketio_path` is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: yes, just tried again. Same 403 error as before - seems like a difficult scrape

Comment: "403 Forbidden" normally means that the request is valid but you are not allowed to make it. Possibly the server requires a cookie? Or similar?

Comment: @Amadan That makes sense, I don't know much about this topic, I'm guessing it has something to do with the `&sid=0hOBuQxbhAw5SHEVAN2F`

Comment: @python_tester did you figure this out sir?